# Remove Non-ASCII characters from File in S3 using Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a CSV file in S3 that has non-printable/non-ascii/junk characters. This is taking a lot of space. My work is to import the file from S3 through Glue and make some transformation and place the updated file in S3.
How can I remove the non-printable/non-ascii/junk characters from the file in S3 using AWS Glue? My sample data is

```
003800019779
```

There are characters after the integer value and that can be viewed when pasted in notepad++

I tried doing:

```
def ascii_ignore(x):
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('acsii')
    
ascii_udf = udf(ascii_ignore)
mapping_node1694802690218 = mapping_node1694802690218.withColumn("UPC",ascii_udf(col("UPC")))
```

getting error as: AttributeError: 'DynamicFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn'
can anyone please help.

Comment: This library could be useful. It replaces unicode characters which visually match those characters. https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, in my case, I am trying to implement this in my Glue job, which is an pyspark code. Can this be implemented there?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. "withColumn' is not a part of DynamicFrame. I had to convert the Dynamic Frame into Data Frame and then use 'withColumn' attribute to implement the regex function like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace 
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame 
data_frames = full_order_node.toDF() ##converting to DataFrame 
data_frames = data_frames.withColumn("featured",regexp_replace(col("featured")," ", "")) 
final_output = DynamicFrame.fromDF(data_frames, glueContext, "final_output") ##converting back to DynamicFrame
```